# How to reinstall LibreOffice from CD?

Tags: installation, libreoffice

I switched to KingSoft Office a few months ago and decided to remove LibreOffice completely. But now I regret, I want to install LibreOffice again and uninstall KingSoft. But after I check the latest version of LibreOffice I have to download 183 MB of the main installer file, which is hurt for my slow Internet connection.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop x32 Live CD. Now, is it possible to reinstall the software with the existing CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that.Do as I say

- Open your software sources and then select install from CD-ROM option as I show in the image ( I am using 13.10 so dont get confuse)
  [image]

There select the cdrom option too.

Then open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Disconnect your internet and then type the command as

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

that will do the Job.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed 12.04 from the CD, it should be listed in your Software Sources. Unmark all the other sources listed temporarily. Then open a Terminal session and issue
`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`
That should perform the install from the files on the CD.